# Accessing Nuget Package Manager console in github actions

Tags: nuget, github-actions, nuget-package-manager-console

I have a fairly messy website project in C#

It has the layout of

```
Foo-EUR
Foo-EUR-Web
```

Where `Foo-EUR` has a csproj file and `Foo-EUR-Web` does not. It's just a website.

To get this to build locally I need to go to the Package Manager console for nuget and enter:

```
Update-Package -reinstall -project Foo-EUR-Web
```

This then copies all the dlls to the folder `Foo-EUR-Web\Bin`

If I don't do this, I get the error:

```
error ASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
```

My problem is I'm trying to build this on github actions. I don't have `Update-Package` available.

I've tried

```
nuget restore src/Foo-EUR.sln
nuget restore src/Foo-EUR/packages.config
nuget restore src/Foo-EUR-Web/packages.config -PackagesDirectory packages
```

Nothing is working.

I think the issue is because there is no csproj, but adding one would be problematic.

Is their a way to install the Nuget Package manager into powershell as a github action to allow me to run `Update-Package` to get this to build ?

Or is there something else I'm missing here with nuget?

The framework version is 4.6.1

Comment: Could either use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-nuget-exe-for-use-with-actions or use a docker with nuget

Comment: Did you try ````dotnet restore```` in given paths? How ````Foo-EUR-Web```` doesn't have .csproj file? It contains only build files?